# Django Form for date range

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to come up with a form that lets the user select a date range to generate a web query in Django. I am having errors getting the date to filter with in my view, I am unable to strip the date.

Here is my `forms.py`:

```
class ReportFiltersForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(input_formats='%Y,%m,%d',widget=SelectDateWidget())
    end_date = forms.DateField(input_formats='%Y,%m,%d',widget=SelectDateWidget())
```

And my view

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReportFiltersForm(request.POST)
    sdy = request.POST['start_date_year']
    sdm = request.POST['start_date_month']
    sdd = request.POST['start_date_day']
    edy = request.POST['end_date_year']
    edm = request.POST['end_date_month']
    edd = request.POST['end_date_day']
    start_date= datetime.date(sdy, sdm, sdd)
    end_date= datetime.date(edy, edm,edd)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 651, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 134, in get_response
return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, exc_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/projects/acms/cms/views.py", line 470, in eventreports
start_date= datetime.date(sdy, sdm, sdd)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: Indentation is significant in Python. I've corrected it here, but please be more careful in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many mistakes you are making here.

First off, to fix your `TypeError`, you need to cast your data into `int` like so:

```
...
sdy = int(request.POST['start_date_year'])
#Do the same with the other 5 fields
```

However, this is a really bad way of doing things. For one, you will have to put `try/except` blocks around each field to make sure the user entered an integer and not a string.

Since you are already using Django Forms, why not let it do all the work for you? Here is how you would do this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReportFiltersForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
        #Do whatever you need to do with this data now. Since you had
        #defined the fields as DateFields, you will automatically get
        #datetime.date objects.
    else:
        return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {'form' : form})
....
```

This is a much better way to do things for a couple of reasons. Using this way, you can let Django take care of validating the user input for you. Additionally, it will also cast this data into `datetime.date` objects. Finally, it will allow you to give better error messages to your user if they entered invalid data.